# order by custom field - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sorting, sql-order-by, custom-fields

I'm trying to sort a page of posts by a custom field.

Here's what I have so far, I'm just not sure how or where to add the orderby

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'new',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'over-make',
            'value' => 'Doral',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )

 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use `orderby` on the same level as `post_type` and `meta_query` in your example.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'post_type' => 'new',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'over-make',
            'value' => 'Doral',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )

 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args);
```

([WordPress Codex: WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters))

Comment: Thanks! I ended up change it to meta_value_num as I'm sorting a number.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably most suitable to use the `get_posts()` function:

```
get_posts('orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=keyname');
```

Sources: [Get Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and [Interacting with WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query) and [Order By Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)

ps. love the idea of ordering by a meta value, hadn't thought of it before, but it could make several different sorting system easier to build, including a popularity mechanism..